# Ubuntu v20.04 troubleshooting login problem

Tags: docker, troubleshooting

After having some login issues, I've reinstalled Ubuntu and it seemed to work fine until yesterday night. It started having login issues again, I've entered the recovery mode and everything seems to be working fine. Here are the details of my disk usage.

[image]

Here is the list of errors/troubles I am getting:

1. watchdog:bug: soft lockup - cpu.
2. Busybox Initramfs Error
3. Firefox seems to be very slow in the environment.
4. Docker image when extracting hangs at one point.

I am new to Ubuntu. Does anyone have any guidance or suggestions?

Comment: Please edit title to reflect the problem more specifically. Your current title does not give any clue what the question is about.

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu might help as well.

Comment: Please see the [site help](https://askubuntu.com/help) for how to ask questions in this site.

Comment: What are the login issues you are experiencing? You seem to have a list of other (unrelated) issues. 